# Access to AWS S3 from AWS Lambda fall into timeout (No VPC)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am currently working on a project that use AWS lambda and AWS S3. I would like to create a Lambda that will write into a S3 bucket. Here is my lambda written in Java :

```
public class WriteIntoBucketHandler implements RequestHandler<SNSEvent, PutObjectResult> {

    @Override
    public PutObjectResult handleRequest(SNSEvent snsEvent, Context context) {
        System.out.println("Connect to S3...");
        AmazonS3 client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient();
        System.out.println("Connected to S3 !");
        System.out.println("Send data to S3...");
        PutObjectResult result =  client.putObject(
                "my-bucket",
                "tata",
                snsEvent.getRecords().get(0).getSNS().getMessage()
        );
        System.out.println("Data sent to S3 !");
        return result;
    }
}
```

This lambda log correctly `Connect to S3...` but fall into timeout just after that and consequently does not display `Connected to S3 !` (timeout is set to 10 secondes)

I configured my lamda to have `AmazonS3FullAccess` and have `no VPC`.

I have already read a lot of posts into internet and stack overflow. I found nothing that can solve it. Anyone have an idea ?

EDIT :

I set timeout to one minute and I got this log before to reach timeout :

```
START RequestId: c300eec4-42bb-4985-9360-7e1e0d9fbdfb Version: $LATEST
Connect to S3...
Metaspace: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468) at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74) at ja
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace
at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.<clinit>(AWSLambda.java:66)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at lambdainternal.LambdaRTEntry.main(LambdaRTEntry.java:114)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace
END RequestId: c300eec4-42bb-4985-9360-7e1e0d9fbdfb
REPORT RequestId: c300eec4-42bb-4985-9360-7e1e0d9fbdfb  Duration: 13202.94 ms   Billed Duration: 13300 ms Memory Size: 128 MB   Max Memory Used: 103 MB
Metaspace java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

Comment: any additional logs from the S3Client? What is the outcome when you increase the timeout to e.g. 60sec?

Comment: The S3 logs not display additional logs. Just that timeout is reached. The timeout default setting of the lambda was set to 3 secondes. I increased it to 10 seconds. I could increase again but I think it will not change anything. Moreover It is suspicous to wait more than 10 seconds in order to write into a bucket. The problem must be come from else where...

Comment: t should not just fail silently. I could image the 10sec timeout kills it before it can print out anything meaningful.Thats why it might be interesting to wait for the timeout within the S3Client to trigger a more insightful error message.

Comment: @gapvision , I set the timeout to 1 minute and I got a new exception before reching timeout. Might be interessting !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I set the lambda to fall into timeout after 1 minute. After that I got a new exception :

```
START RequestId: c300eec4-42bb-4985-9360-7e1e0d9fbdfb Version: $LATEST
Connect to S3...
Metaspace: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468) at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74) at ja
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace
at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.<clinit>(AWSLambda.java:66)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at lambdainternal.LambdaRTEntry.main(LambdaRTEntry.java:114)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace
END RequestId: c300eec4-42bb-4985-9360-7e1e0d9fbdfb
REPORT RequestId: c300eec4-42bb-4985-9360-7e1e0d9fbdfb  Duration: 13202.94 ms   Billed Duration: 13300 ms Memory Size: 128 MB   Max Memory Used: 103 MB
Metaspace java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

As it said in this exception 128MB is not enought to instance the S3 client. S3 client need at least 192MB so I had to increase my lambda size memory.

**Important note** : Only the first instance take more that 10 seconds to be executed. All lambda executions will be far more faster after that. After 1 hour, however, the lambda will need to authenticate again and will take more than 10 seconds.

Comment: great that you found a solution! I think its not actually the authentication which takes so long but the general boot-up of the lambda. Keep in mind that lambdas have a cold-start problem which is exactly what you describe: If not called for period of time, the first call will take significantly longer. It is not actually the authentication but the lambda itself.